# didSelectRowAt: IndexPath is not working and will not print to the console when the cell pressed on

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib

I have an xib file which is a custom cell that is being loaded programmatically onto the tableview on the view controller. However, it never runs the function `didSelectRowAt` and print to the console.

[Screen capture of the current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SghP.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't post images, post code (text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming functions like `numberOfRows(in section:)` and `cellForRow(at indexPath:)` are working, it seems that your `UITableView`'s `dataSource` is set to `ThumbnailViewModel`, but not your `UITableView`'s `delegate` property.

Wherever you've set `dataSource` be sure to set your `UITableView`'s `delegate` property to be the `ThumbnailViewModel`.

**Real cause:**
Try changing `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath)` to `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: I have the lines: "tableView?.delegate = ThumbnailViewModel
        tableView?.dataSource = ThumbnailViewModel" in my code it still doesn't work

Comment: Is the tableView responding to touch, i.e. scrolling etc.?

Comment: Yes, it highlights when clicked on the cell.

Comment: Try changing `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath)` to `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: It worked thank you so much!

Comment: I'll edit my answer, be sure to choose it as correct. You're welcome.